# How do you speed up Dialogflow CX speech recognition on single word responses?

Tags: speech-to-text, dialogflow-cx

I have a Dialogflow CX agent working in polish [pl] language as an audio bot using AudioCodes.

I want it to respond to yes/no answers (pl: "tak"/"nie"), yet it takes usually 15 seconds or more to detect the end of utterance. Enabling advanced speech settings and setting "End of speech sensitivity" and "No speech timeout" does not help.

I'd love to set some Audiocodes parameters, like [fast STT recognition](https://techdocs.audiocodes.com/voice-ai-connect/Content/VAIG_Combined/speech_customization.htm#Fast20STT20recognition), but I don't know where to set them.

Any ideas on how to speed up the detection time? Forcing users to respond with two or more words is not allowed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "End of speech sensitivity" in Dialogflow CX is only available for agents using the en-US language tag, as seen [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/agent#settings-speech).